# Nesting elements dynamically in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner with React, and I wish to try and create dynamically the number of content rows and boxes depending on the amount of content I have available, but while creating the rows is easy, for some reason it doesn't seem to be possible to embed the boxes into them in the same manner. Here's an example of the code that I've been trying to work with so far:

EDIT (Clarifying the code):

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const yAxis = ["y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "y5"];
const xAxis = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"];

const rows = yAxis.map((row) =>
  <div key={row.toString()} className={"boxrow " + row.toString()} >
    {boxes}
  </div>
);

const boxes = xAxis.map((box) =>
  <div key={box.toString()} className={"box " + box.toString()}>
    {box}
  </div>
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="rows">
          {rows}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What I would like to know, why can't I simply embed the boxes-method inside the rows-method? I was under the impression that this sort of thing was exactly what React was designed for.

EDIT:

Alternately, I tried the following approach, only for it to result in errors:

Main index:

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Boxes from './Boxes'; 
import Rows from './Rows';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<Rows />, document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

Boxes:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const xAxis = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"];

class Boxes extends Component {
    boxes = xAxis.map((box) =>
        <div key={box.toString()} className="box ">
            {box}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Boxes;
```

Rows:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Boxes from './Boxes';

const yAxis = ["y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "y5"];

class Rows extends Component {
    rows = yAxis.map((row) =>
        <div key={row.toString()} className="boxrow">
            <Boxes />
        </div>
    );

}

export default Rows;
```

Comment: Where are you calling the components `<boxes />` and `<rows />`?
If you created the constants `yAxis` and `xAxis` out of your parent component, you won't be able to use them inside of your parent component

Comment: Honestly, I was hoping to call them as a single module; all this was supposed to take place inside a single <content /> tag. If it's necessary to make multiple classes, I'll do it, but I thought to start as simple as possible with this concept.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were trying to produce:

```js
    const yAxis = ["y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "y5"];
    const xAxis = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"];

    class Box extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>{this.props.boxes.map((box) =>
            <div>{box}</div>
          )}</div>
        );
      }
    }

    class Row extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>{this.props.rows.map((row) =>
            <div>{<Box boxes={xAxis}/>}</div>
          )}</div>
        );
      }
    }

    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
            <div className="rows">
              <Row rows={yAxis}/>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

One thing I noticed is that your stateless components were not structured properly. They should return a single component.

Second, you should really try to make use of `props`.

Comment: Ah, of course. I was aware of the single component return structure, but I got so frustrated working on one method that I ended up completely missing the forest from the trees, and losing the sight of it. I am starting to get the hang of this, now. I got my test grid working in one way, now, I'll start refining it more tomorrow. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Please feel free to select a best answer to your question!